# How can I use 2 data bindings for an ItemSource Data Template in WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a counter which increments depending on a foreach Loop from:

```
public partial class UserControlCounter : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _scanStatusCounter;
    public int ScanStatusCounter
    {
        get { return _scanStatusCounter; }
        set { _scanStatusCounter = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public UserControlCounter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        await Task.Run(getAll);
        scanStatus.Text = "Persons " + ScanStatusCounter.ToString();
    }


    private async void getAll()
    {
        //grab data and iterate it
        string[] string_array = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" }; // type = System.String[]

        foreach (var i in string_array)
        {

            ScanStatusCounter++;
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and the Xaml:

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="myListBox" Height="40" ></ListBox>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="scanStatus" Height="40" Text="{Binding Path=ScanStatusCounter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Click="Button_Click" Height="40">Click Me</Button>
</Grid>
```

That works fine and increments "live", but my problem is that I need to get that now running inside a more complex Data Template.

I've tried to inject the Counter onClick with:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var btn = sender as Button;
        var contentPresenter = (btn.TemplatedParent as ContentPresenter);

        var ppStatusCounter = contentPresenter.ContentTemplate.FindName("scanStatus", contentPresenter) as TextBlock;
      ppStatusCounter.Text = "Entrys found: " + ScanStatusCounter.ToString();

    }
```

But then I get the Value only onClick not like a live incrementing Counter, that's my Data Template:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <c1:NameList x:Key="NameListData"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="NameItemTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Domaine"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="txtDomainName" Text="{Binding Path=DomaineName}" Margin="0,0,5,0"></TextBox>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="5,5,5,5" x:Name="btnNames" Click="Button_Click" Content="Start Scan" />
            <Grid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"  Height="20">
                <ProgressBar x:Name="pbStatus" Height="20" Width="100" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="pbStatusText" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Scanning" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Name="scanStatus" Text="{Binding Path=ScanStatusCounter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

 <Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="top">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <ListBox x:Name="lstDomainNames" 
                                     Margin="5,5,5,5" 
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource NameListData}}"  
                                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NameItemTemplate}"  
                                     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

that's my Data Source Class, not much there:

```
 public partial class NameList : ObservableCollection<SetCredentials>
{

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public NameList() : base()
    {
        using var forest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
        Forest currentForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
        DomainCollection domains = currentForest.Domains;
        foreach (Domain objDomain in domains)
        {
            Add(new SetCredentials(objDomain.ToString()));
        }
    }

}

public class SetCredentials
{
    private string domainName;


    public SetCredentials(string domain)
    {
        this.domainName = domain;

    }

    public string DomaineName
    {
        get { return domainName; }
        set { domainName = value; }
    }

    
}
```

Do I have to add a second Data Binding source to my ItemSource or do I need another approach for this, for example in my TextBox Binding?

Comment: Turn `private async void getAll()` into `private async Task getAll()` and `await Task.Run(getAll)` into `await getAll()`.

Comment: perfect, works! Thank you